# How to lock-down a frame in Java (GUI)

Tags: java, user-interface, frameworks, awt

I'm starting a Java project and need a way to completely lock down a frame. By lock down I mean:

- Users can't close it
- Users can't drag it
- Users can't minimize it
- It lies on top of the taskbar and everything else (unless specified)

Basically, it's a full screen takeover.

Comment: @MaxMaxkie: "Is something like this possible to do?"  I sure hope not.

Comment: Google Java Kiosk or Java Kiosk mode since this I believe is what you're looking for. Most solutions I've seen require some code that interacts directly with the OS, so you will likely need to use JNA or JNI.

Comment: I looked into the Kiosk mode but I think this would be too much work (using JNA or JNI), when I might be able to get Full Screen Exclusive to work.

Comment: yep it's a lot of work, but if you truly want Kiosk function, it's what you'll need to do. I hope that you're planning on using this on dedicated Kiosk workstations rather than commandeer some poor schlub's computer.

Comment: Actually this is a project for a mobile kiosk type of thing, but it's only to create some kind of a menu (that can run shell commands and stuff). Seeing as you can escape full screen in java with Alt+F4 and Alt+Tab, I'm thinking of figuring out a way in Java to catch keystrokes and disable them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [fullscreen exclusive mode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/exclusivemode.html) and see if it works for you.

Comment: From what I've read this seems risky. The link you provided keeps referring to the possibility that a machine might not support this. How likely is a machine to actually support it and it not be dangerous?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class FullScreenTest extends JFrame {

    private GraphicsDevice device;
    private boolean isFullScreen = false;

    public FullScreenTest(GraphicsDevice device) {
        super(device.getDefaultConfiguration());
        this.device = device;
        setTitle("Display Mode Test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void initComponents(Container c) {
        setContentPane(c);
        c.setBackground(Color.RED);
    }

    public void begin() {
        isFullScreen = device.isFullScreenSupported();
        setUndecorated(isFullScreen);
        setResizable(!isFullScreen);
        if (isFullScreen) {
            // Full-screen mode
            device.setFullScreenWindow(this);
            validate();
        } else {
            // Windowed mode
            pack();
            setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.
            getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice[] devices = env.getScreenDevices();
        FullScreenTest test = new FullScreenTest(devices[0]);
        test.initComponents(test.getContentPane());
        test.begin();
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran this code and I get a teensy weensy little window :) Could that be my device?

Comment: @MaxMackie Can you print out the value if `isFullScreen` boolean and let me know what it is?

Comment: Actually got this to work, thanks alot for this -- it's exactly what I need. However, will this work on any computer? What are it's limitations?

Comment: On second thought, I don't think the full-screen exclusive mode will help you achieve what you want to do. Although the app shows as full-screen, on my Mac OS 10.6 machine, I could easily kill the process with Cmd-Q. One of your requirements is that the user should not be able to close the app, rt? Please see http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/awt/AWTChanges.html#fullscreen and http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4189326 for more details on full-screen exclusive mode.

Comment: Yeah I was playing around with it and it can be killed. But aren't ALT-F4 and things like that simply keyboard shortcuts? Can they be disabled?